# Maven dependency and non-maven dependency conflict

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, dependencies

I have a project that has some dependencies. Some of those dependencies are Mavenized and some of them aren't.

Two dependencies use the same class, but from different packages, one from Java Libs and the other one from GWT libs. This makes the app crash.

MyPackage Depends On: Package A
MyPacakge Depends On: Package B

Package B and Package A are conflicting.

Currently the only solution I've found was to exclude one the conflicted dependencies.

Is there any plugin for Eclipse-Maven or any workaround to easily solve this?.

Thanks.

Comment: You can exclude libs in maven https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,2 or more classes with the same package path and same class name mixed in the class path,the first class loaded will come into use,and the later ones are all ignored.And no exception or even currution will happen.
This jvm class loading rule is frequently used in enterprise app to fix bugs quickly.Make a jar named with name of 'a_name_yyyyMMddHHmmss.jar' to replace the mis-coded java class with out compiling the whole projects and upgrading.
Would you please add your exception log or something?

I have several advise:

1. Make sure the GWT version and jdk version the 'same'/compatible.
2. Use the "Dependency Exclusions" of maven pom config.Refer [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).